# Serialization error while writing JSON to file

Tags: json, scala, playframework, apache-spark

I am reading text files and creating Json objects `JsValues` in every iteration. I want to save them to a file at every iteration. I am using Play Framework to create JSON objects.

```
class Cleaner {
  def getDocumentData() = {
     for (i <- no_of_files) {
     .... do something ...
         some_json = Json.obj("text" -> LARGE_TEXT)
         final_json = Json.stringify(some_json)
         //save final_json here to a file
     }
  }
}
```

I tried using `PrintWriter` to save that json but I am getting `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` as the error.

How should I correct this? or is there any other way I can save the JsValue?

UPDATE:

I read that the trait `serializable` has to be used in this case. I have the following function:

```
class Cleaner() extends Serializable {
  def readDocumentData() {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("linkin_spark")
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
      .set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "1")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val temp = sc.wholeTextFiles("text_doc.dat)
    val docStartRegex = """<DOC>""".r
    val docEndRegex = """</DOC>""".r
    val docTextStartRegex = """<TEXT>""".r
    val docTextEndRegex = """</TEXT>""".r
    val docnoRegex = """<DOCNO>(.*?)</DOCNO>""".r
    val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.json"))

    for (fileData <- temp) {
      val filename = fileData._1
      val content: String = fileData._2
      println(s"For $filename, the data is:")
      var startDoc = false // This is for the
      var endDoc = false // whole file
      var startText = false //
      var endText = false //
      var textChunk = new ListBuffer[String]()
      var docID: String = ""
      var es_json: JsValue = Json.obj()

      for (current_line <- content.lines) {
        current_line match {
          case docStartRegex(_*) => {
            startDoc = true
            endText = false
            endDoc = false
          }
          case docnoRegex(group) => {
            docID = group.trim
          }
          case docTextStartRegex(_*) => {
            startText = true
          }
          case docTextEndRegex(_*) => {
            endText = true
            startText = false
          }
          case docEndRegex(_*) => {
            endDoc = true
            startDoc = false
            es_json = Json.obj(
              "_id" -> docID,
              "_source" -> Json.obj(
                "text" -> textChunk.mkString(" ")
              )
            )
            writer.write(es_json.toString())
            println(es_json.toString())
            textChunk.clear()
          }
          case _ => {
            if (startDoc && !endDoc && startText) {
              textChunk += current_line.trim
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    writer.close()
  }
}
```

This is function to which I added the trait but still I am getting the same exception.
I rewrote a smaller version of it:

```
def foo() {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("linkin_spark")
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
      .set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "1")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    var es_json: JsValue = Json.obj()
    val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.json"))
    for (i <- 1 to 10) {
      es_json = Json.obj(
        "_id" -> i,
        "_source" -> Json.obj(
          "text" -> "Eureka!"
        )
      )
      println(es_json)
      writer.write(es_json.toString() + "\n")
    }
    writer.close()
  }
```

This function works fine with and also without `serializable`. I cannot understand what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: First answer made on phone.

It's not your main class that needs to be serializable but the class you use in the rdd processing loop in this case inside `for (fileData <- temp)`
It needs to be serializable because the spark data is on multiple partitions that may be on multiple computers. So the functions you apply to this data need to be serializable so you can send them to the other computer where they will be executed in parallel.
`PrintWriter` cannot be serializable since it refers to a file that is only available from the original computer. Hence the serializaion error.

To write your data on the computer initializing the spark process. You need to take the data that is all over the cluster and bring it to your machine then write it.

To do that you can either collect the result. `rdd.collect()` and that will take all the data from the cluster and put it in your driver thread memory. Then you can write it to a file using the `PrintWriter`.

like this:

```
temp.flatMap { fileData =>
  val filename = fileData._1
  val content: String = fileData._2
  println(s"For $filename, the data is:")
  var startDoc = false // This is for the
  var endDoc = false // whole file
  var startText = false //
  var endText = false //
  var textChunk = new ListBuffer[String]()
  var docID: String = ""
  var es_json: JsValue = Json.obj()

  var results = ArrayBuffer[String]()

  for (current_line <- content.lines) {
    current_line match {
      case docStartRegex(_*) => {
        startDoc = true
        endText = false
        endDoc = false
      }
      case docnoRegex(group) => {
        docID = group.trim
      }
      case docTextStartRegex(_*) => {
        startText = true
      }
      case docTextEndRegex(_*) => {
        endText = true
        startText = false
      }
      case docEndRegex(_*) => {
        endDoc = true
        startDoc = false
        es_json = Json.obj(
          "_id" -> docID,
          "_source" -> Json.obj(
            "text" -> textChunk.mkString(" ")
          )
        )
        results.append(es_json.toString())
        println(es_json.toString())
        textChunk.clear()
      }
      case _ => {
        if (startDoc && !endDoc && startText) {
          textChunk += current_line.trim
        }
      }
    }
  }

  results
}
.collect()
.foreach(es_json => writer.write(es_json))
```

If the result is too large for the driver thread memory you can use the saveAsTextFile function that will stream each partition to your drive. In this second case the path you give as argument will be made into a folder and each partition of your rdd will be written to a numbered file in it.

like this:

```
temp.flatMap { fileData =>
  val filename = fileData._1
  val content: String = fileData._2
  println(s"For $filename, the data is:")
  var startDoc = false // This is for the
  var endDoc = false // whole file
  var startText = false //
  var endText = false //
  var textChunk = new ListBuffer[String]()
  var docID: String = ""
  var es_json: JsValue = Json.obj()

  var results = ArrayBuffer[String]()

  for (current_line <- content.lines) {
    current_line match {
      case docStartRegex(_*) => {
        startDoc = true
        endText = false
        endDoc = false
      }
      case docnoRegex(group) => {
        docID = group.trim
      }
      case docTextStartRegex(_*) => {
        startText = true
      }
      case docTextEndRegex(_*) => {
        endText = true
        startText = false
      }
      case docEndRegex(_*) => {
        endDoc = true
        startDoc = false
        es_json = Json.obj(
          "_id" -> docID,
          "_source" -> Json.obj(
            "text" -> textChunk.mkString(" ")
          )
        )
        results.append(es_json.toString())
        println(es_json.toString())
        textChunk.clear()
      }
      case _ => {
        if (startDoc && !endDoc && startText) {
          textChunk += current_line.trim
        }
      }
    }
  }

  results
}
.saveAsTextFile("test.json")
```

Comment: I couldn't get you. The class where I am trying to process the `es_json` is `serializable`.

Comment: Yes but `PrinterWriter` is not serializable and cannot be serializable. So the error comes from using the `writer` val in the `for (data <- temp)` loop.